# how to install 32bit support in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit?

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, cpu-architecture

```
sudo apt-add-architecture i386
```

The above command does not work in *Ubuntu 16.04 64bit*
I need *32bit* support, how can I do?